# Invalid Content-Length and Client sent malformed Host header

Tags: apache, centos

I got this log from apache httpd log file
Can u help troubleshooting

Thanks

```
[Wed Apr 26 02:40:13 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/wa.exe
[Wed Apr 26 02:40:13 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/wa.exe
[Wed Apr 26 02:40:14 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/whois.cgi
[Wed Apr 26 02:40:14 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/whois.cgi
[Wed Apr 26 02:40:36 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] script '/var/www/cgi-bin/contact.php' not found or unable to stat
[Wed Apr 26 02:40:38 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/counter.exe
[Wed Apr 26 02:40:58 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/hosting
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:02 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] script '/var/www/cgi-bin/form.php' not found or unable to stat
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:05 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] script '/var/www/cgi-bin/comments.php' not found or unable to stat
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:08 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/projects_site
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:46 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:47 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:47 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length

[Wed Apr 26 02:41:49 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:50 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:50 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:51 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:51 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:51 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:41:52 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length

[Wed Apr 26 02:43:02 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:03 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:03 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:04 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:04 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:04 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:05 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:05 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:06 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Invalid Content-Length
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:20 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Client sent malformed Host header
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:20 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Client sent malformed Host header
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:31 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Client sent malformed Host header
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:31 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Client sent malformed Host header
[Wed Apr 26 02:43:31 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Client sent malformed Host header
```

what special configuration should I have for httpd
the x.x.x.x refers to our IP address so it is not an attack from outside.

Comment: No worries . Our security team was running scans that created this error.. I forget to check that : File does not exist: /var/www/error/nessus

Answer (score 0):

No worries . Our security team was running scans that created this error.. I forget to check that : File does not exist: /var/www/error/nessus